# How to use Vim to format file from command line

Tags: command-line, vim, text-formatting

I have some Django HTML templates that I'd like to auto-format. I've read Vim has a ["htmldjango"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/OFiGX537hA8) format that can be applied, but I don't want to manually open every single file and apply it.

How do I run a Vim command from the command line to apply this formatting to one or more files in a single batch?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23235290/5164855) should do what you want. It describes the use of batch mode in a Windows environment, though the translation to Linux should be obvious.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this:

```
vim -c "argdo setf htmldjango | execute 'normal! gg=G' | update" file1 file2 ...
```

`:argdo` iterates over all passed files. After ensuring the desired *filetype*, the file is re-indented (`gg=G`) and saved.

You can append `-c quitall` to automatically quit Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script, `beautify.sh`, that will format any file at the command line, using [Neovim](https://neovim.io/).

It should work with any file format that vim itself recognizes, so javascript, json, c, java, etc. It's not a true formatter, but more of a nice indenter.

#### Example usage:

```
$ cat /tmp/it.json
{
"images": [
{
"time": 2.86091,
"transaction":
{
"status": "Complete",
"gallery_name": "gallerytest1",
}
}
}

$ cat /tmp/it.json | beautify.sh
{
        "images": [
        {
                "time": 2.86091,
                        "transaction":
                        {
                                "status": "Complete",
                                "gallery_name": "gallerytest1",
                        }
        }
}
```

#### beautify.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function show_help()
{
  ME=$(basename $0)
  IT=$(CAT <<EOF

  Format a file at the command line using neovim

  usage: cat /some/file | $ME 
         $ME /some/file
  )
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi

# Determine if we're processing a file from stdin or args
if [ -p /dev/stdin ]; then
  FILE=$(mktemp)
  cat > $FILE
  FROM_STDIN=true
else
  if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    show_help
  fi
  FILE="$*"
  FROM_STDIN=false
fi

# put vim commands in a temp file to use to do the formatting
TMP_VIM_CMDS_FILE=$(mktemp)
rm -f $TMP_VIM_CMDS_FILE 
echo "gg=G" > $TMP_VIM_CMDS_FILE 
echo ":wq" >> $TMP_VIM_CMDS_FILE 

# run neovim to do the formatting
nvim --headless --noplugin -n -u NONE -s $TMP_VIM_CMDS_FILE $FILE &> /dev/null

# show output and cleanup
rm -f $TMP_VIM_CMDS_FILE 
if [ "$FROM_STDIN" == "true" ]
then
  cat $FILE
  rm -f $FILE
fi
```